# Jenkins build failed with Revision error

Tags: python, git, jenkins

I was trying to run Jenkins on a simple Python test. It's my first time, so I followed steps mentioned in this tutorial : [Link](http://blog.clickthisnick.com/continuous-integration-ui-automation-test/)

My Jenkins console output after I triggered build shows that it failed because it couldn't find any revision.

Here is the console output :

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace    /usr/share/tomcat7/.jenkins/jobs/PythonUIProject/workspace
> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> git config remote.origin.url /home/rahul/PycharmProjects/.git/ # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from /home/rahul/PycharmProjects/.git/
> git --version # timeout=10
> git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress /home/rahul/PycharmProjects/.git/ +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*


Seen 0 remote branches
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
Finished: FAILURE
```

My Git installation folder is : `home/rahul/PycharmProjects/`, and my system is a `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`.

I tried changing the `Branches to Build` under the `Source Code Management configuration` to be `**` in place of `*/master` as a workaround but it didn't work.

Has anybody worked on this before? What should be the solution to this.

Edit 1 : As per suggestions I tried using the `git push` to push the code, but I am getting this :

```
  rahul@oneplusone:~/PycharmProjects$ git push -u /home/rahul/PycharmProjects/.git master
  error: src refspec master does not match any.
  error: failed to push some refs to '/home/rahul/PycharmProjects/.git'
```

Comment: Did you `git push`? It seems to be missing from the tutorial you linked.

Comment: Can you add the Jenkins job git related configuration settings?

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: did you have added origin for your git repository ? first you push your repository to bitbuckt or gitlab etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your branches have been pushed up. Failing that, you can try to remove the '*/' from your branch (just use `master` instead of `*/master`)

Comment: Added some edit. I changed it to master but saw the same error

Comment: looks like your repo is misconfigured. you need a 'remote' to push to (a place to store your code). Do you have a github repo or something you wish to save this code on?

Comment: Well no. This file is on my local system. I don't have a github file if that is what you are implying. Though I havent tried the remote command